# f(text) not f('text') in postgres function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres function:

```
create function abc(text) returns text as $$
    select a from table_name where table_name.column = $1;
$$ language SQL;
```

I've noticed that the input must be put in quotes:

```
select * from abc('hello');
```

and I'm wondering if there is any way to make it so that I can do

```
select * from abc(hello);
```

Comment: No there isn't. The SQL syntax requires character constants to be put into single quotes. Anything without quotes is a reference to a column or table.

Comment: What means hello in this case?  it  is another column name ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze no it is a value that can be taken by one of the columns in the table i am querying

Comment: Imagine if you put text without quotes. How to distinguish it from column reference or variable? You may want to call this function not only with string literal parameter, but also with a data from variable. How to say it to pgsql - where take value for argument?

Comment: BTW, what problem do you want to solve?

Comment: The question is the tip of an iceberg. You are hiding what you are trying to solve.

Comment: I think @a_horse_with_no_name answered sufficiently. I had seen someone write it that way but it must've been a mistake